# Como fazer Gráfico Expansivel no Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

Estou tentando fazer um gráfico expansivel, que se ajusta automaticamente, porém estou utilizando essa fórmula e não está dando certo. Alguém pode me ajudar?

```html
=DESLOC(CTC!$B$3;1;0;CONT.VALORES(CTC!$B$4:$B$18;"<>"&"0");1)

OU

=DESLOC(CTC!$B$3;1;0;CONT.VALORES(CTC!$B$4:$B$18;"<>0");1)
```

Como pode ver no gráfico não era pra estar aparecendo valores zero, e nem nulo, acrescentei no final da fórmula o: "<>"&"0" porém mesmo assim não ta funcionando, minha intenção com isso era "Se for diferente de 0, continua

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score -1):

Olá,

Para a fórmula que busca os status, tente usar:
`=DESLOC(CTC!$A$4;0;0;CONT.SE(CTC!$B:$B;">0");1)`

Ela vai buscar tudo o que é maior do que ZERO na coluna B, em vez de buscar tudo o que for diferente de ZERO. O problema de usar tudo o que for diferente de ZERO é que o Excel entende as células vazias como ZERO.

Para a fórmula que busca os valores, tente usar:
`=DESLOC(CTC!$B$4;0;0;CONT.SE(CTC!$B:$B;">0");1)`

O racional é o mesmo, mas agora a fórmula busca as nomenclaturas da coluna A baseado nos valores (tudo o que for maior que ZERO) da coluna B.